# Confusion with "every path from a given node to any of the leaves goes through the same number of black nodes" property of RB trees

Tags: trees, binary-trees, red-black-trees

One of the properties of Red Black trees is: "every path from a given node/vertex to any of the leaves goes through the same number of black nodes"

Two related questions about this property:

1) is the vertex we start at counted in this black vertex count?

2) is the leaf we end at counted in the black vertex count?

I have a secret theory about both of these questions, but am hoping for confirmation and so shalt not yet reveal it.